# res.download crashing the browser

Tags: node.js, express

Im trying to send a file on the server to the browser as a download. res.download is cashing the browser.

Any ideas?

Code

```
        var filename = path.basename(userPathZip);
        var mimetype = mime.lookup(userPathZip);

        res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=test.zip');
        res.setHeader('Content-type', mimetype);

        var filestream = fsextra.createReadStream(userPathZip);
        filestream.pipe(res);
```

in the network tab in chrome the response is 24mb which is the size of the file so im not sure whats goin on here

Comment: Are you doing this in response to an XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: Yes. Im using meanjs framework

Comment: You should almost never be responding to an XHR with binary data like that. You should open up that link in the browser which will prompt the user to save whatever you're sending.

Answer (score 0):

var filename = path.basename(userPathZip);
    var mimetype = mime.lookup(userPathZip);

```
res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=test.zip');
res.setHeader('Content-type', mimetype);

var filestream = fsextra.createReadStream(userPathZip);
filestream.pipe(res);
```

it is res.pipe(filestream);

Comment: How could you handle this on the front end using Angularjs

Answer (score 0):

What would be the best was to serve files to admin only? Don't want the files making it to a public folder